# Check a radio box

Tags: applescript

How can I check a radio box with applescript?

I've tried this but just get 'missing value'

```
do JavaScript "var elements = document.getElementsByName('radiobs');
for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  if(elements[i].value == 'Help') {
    elements[i].checked = true;
  }
}" in document 1
```

Here's the radio box:

```
<input name="radiobs" id="radiobs" type="radio" value="No help">
<input name="radiobs" id="radiobs" type="radio" value="Help">
<input name="radiobs" id="radiobs" type="radio" value="Some help">
```

Comment: Works as expected in Safari 7.0.6 on 10.9.5... I created a new file with your form only and the radio button switched using your script!

Comment: Perhaps it's my safari then - 8.0.5

Comment: Just tried it in Chrome - does not work

Answer (score 0):

The way to call Javascript is different in Chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1
        execute tab (active tab index) javascript "var elements = document.getElementsByName('radiobs');
for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  if(elements[i].value == 'Help') {
    elements[i].checked = true;
  }
}"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, but still cant get it to work - the console in chrome outputs "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" when i try your script

Comment: You talked about AppleScript, you tried the Script inside Applescript Editor, didn't you?

Comment: Yes this is inside the editor. I just noticed what the console in Chrome was outputting. The script editor still says missing value with the above.